# Why doesn't this while loop end?

Tags: c++, while-loop

I copied this code from C++ Primer as an example for while loops, and it doesn't output anything.  I'm using g++.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int sum = 0, val = 1;
    // keep executing the while as long val is less than or equal to 10
    while (val <= 10) {
        sum += val;     // assigns sum+ val to sum\
        ++val;          // add 1 to val
    }
    std::cout << "Sum of 1 to 10 inclusive is "
              << sum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
sum += val;     // assigns sum+ val to sum\
```

Get rid of the backslash at the end of the line. That's a line continuation character. It causes the next line to be concatenated to this line; in other words, `++val` becomes part of the "assigns sum+ val to sum" comment.

Comment: This is a perfect example of why [MCVE]s are important.

Answer (score 4):

```
    sum += val;     // assigns sum+ val to sum\ <-- typo
    ++val;          // add 1 to val
```

You got a typo at that `sum += val;` line. The "\" at the end make the following line a comment, thus making the `while` an infinite loop as `val` was never increased. Remove "\", then it would work.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple mistake, remove the \ after the comment "// assigns sum+ val to sum".